# Programmatically Setting Custom Permissions for Google Sites Pages

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I'm currently creating a Google Site for staff where I work. We would like each staff member to have their own page that only they can view with details such as rota's, shift itinerary etc. We would not like other members of staff be able to view this. The current idea I have for implementing this is to run a script that generates a page for each user with the custom permissions set so only editors and themselves can view it. However, although I am aware you can set site wide permissions through Google Scripts, I can not find a way to set page wide custom permissions programmatically.

Is anyone aware of a way I can do this or if there is an alternative way to achieve the same goal?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the following link:
https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2934

And also check out the following link (check comment #15):
https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1021

(comment #15): A work around you can use is to add a group with the permissions you require and then from Apps Script you can programmatically add/remove people from the group.

If you want Google engineers to develop this functionality then vote for this issue on the above link.

Comment: Thank you for your links and I have voted on the issue. Your workaround will work for one aspect of what I am doing, however, programatically adding permission for a single individual to their personal page will not work for this so I shall have to try and find a workaround for that until the feature is released.

Thank you for your help.